# Here is a question of differential equation in the chapter of non-homogeneous part.

Tags: calculus

> Solve the following IVPs for the given initial data, and express the solution in the form $$y(x) = \int_0^xK(x - t)f(t) \, dt$$ for some function $K(s)$ of a single variable.
>
> $y'' - 2y' + y = f(x), y(0) = y'(0) = 0$

I tried solving it in this using the formula in the nonhomogeneous equation but didn't solve it out. Any tips on the method that can apply on?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD28r.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! It would be nice, if you could write your calculations using MathJax inside your question body as described [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Using the Laplace transform we have

$$
Y(s) = \frac{F(s)}{s^2-2s+1}
$$

and now use convolution.

NOTE

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^2-2s+1}\right) = t e^t
$$